# how to order items in a cakephp tree

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have 3 tables. products, categories, categories_products.

Each product has and belongs to many categories. And my Categories is a Tree. Now, I need to order the products. So... ? Ideas? :D

Comment: Order them by what? Your question is way too vague to answer.

Comment: Please add your controller's code in your question in order for us to see what you are doing at the moment.

Comment: i will face the same problem in some days, so i know what this is about. its about ordering the products in each single category and about how to approach this problem.

Comment: If you don't want to order via the product `id` or `name` (e.g. alphabetically, you would need an `order` column, which you could rearrange/update. You can also apply tree-like behaviour to the products model, but would require some extra work

Comment: This is far too ambiguous and vague to answer.  Order like sorting?  Order like purchase?

Answer (score 1):

Use [reorder](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1355/reorder) method.